# CSP PHP issue LottiePlayer

Tags: javascript, php, security, web, content-security-policy

I use nonce generation via PHP, fastcgi:

```
fastcgi_param NONCE $nonce;
```

In the CSP I have added (using NGINX + header):

```
script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-${nonce}'
```

The whole CSP looks like this:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'self'; base-uri 'none'; form-action 'self'; script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-${nonce}'; script-src-elem 'self'; connect-src 'self' 'nonce-${nonce}' https://www.w3.org; img-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; style-src 'self'";
```

Adding via PHP:

```
nonce="<?= $_SERVER['NONCE']?>"
```

In DevTools I see only:

```
nonce
```

Without:

```
nonce="number"
```

Is it correct?

**This was resolved as it is as it should be.**

Main issue is that I see in DevTools error which comes from using lottie player script and it says that I don't use nonce, or sha hash which I for sure do.

The error is as follows:

```
lottie-player.js:1 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-4Czhp/5smweUxQ0BkhMh9cmbPz4zsdDHhq70HOQBcHY='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.
```

The error occurs for every lottie used via:

```
 <lottie-player></lottie-player>
```

This is the script calling:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lottie-player.js" nonce="<?= $_SERVER['REQUEST_ID'] ?>"></script>
```

Usage:

```
<lottie-player src="/main.json" background="transparent" speed="1" autoplay></lottie-player>
```

I have also tried to add nonce directly to the lottie-player, which would look like this:

```
<lottie-player src="/main.json" background="transparent" speed="1" autoplay nonce="<?= $_SERVER['REQUEST_ID'] ?>"></lottie-player>
```

But that wasn't the fix and that's why I am seeking for help.

Comment: Please share more details. What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: _“In DevTools I see only: `nonce` Without: `nonce="number"` Is it correct?”_ - yes, I think that’s as it should be. The browser has to hide the value from being accessed by other scripts (see also, [MDN: Accessing nonces and nonce hiding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/nonce#accessing_nonces_and_nonce_hiding)), so likely it is hidden from dev tools in the same way. You‘ll need to check the actual HTML source code your browser received, if you want to verify it was populated correctly.

Comment: @NicoHaase, I can't resolve this:

`lottie-player.js:1 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-4Czhp/5smweUxQ0BkhMh9cmbPz4zsdDHhq70HOQBcHY='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.` The nonce was added to the script but I still receive this error.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. This should not only contain error messages, but also the code involved and your attepmts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Briefly**: make whole CSP looks like:

`add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'self'; base-uri 'none'; form-action 'self'; script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-${nonce}'; script-src-elem 'self'; connect-src 'self' https://www.w3.org; img-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'";`

What is changed:

- `script-src-elem 'self';` is removed at all
- `'nonce-${nonce}'` is removed from the `connect-src` directive, it's not supported there
- `'unsafe-inline'` is addes to `style-src` directive

*Note* that Safari [does not support](https://csplite.com/csp/test214/#bug_Safari_strict-dynamic) `'strict-dynamic'`, therefore it may need to add some host-sources for secondary scripts.

> 

**TD; DR;** or what's going on

1. Main issue that you have a CSP violation in the `STYLE-src` ("Refused to apply **inline style** it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: **"style-src 'self'"**"). But you are trying to fix it by addinig `'nonce-value'` into the `SCRIPT-src`. You have to add `'nonce-value'` into `style-src` directive and `nonce='value'` attribute into all `<style>` tags. In case of usage inline styles kind of `<tag style='...'>`, the `nonce` is not useful at all (therefore at this stage it was solved via `'unsafe-inline'`).
2. Chrome browser supports `script-src-elem` directive, therefore Chrome will not use `script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-${nonce}'` and will use `script-src-elem 'self';` for all `<scrit>` and `<script src='...'>` tags. I do not think it's what you wish.
   Other browsers will ignore `script-src-elem` and will use `script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-${nonce}'`, but Safari will ignore `'strict-dynamic'`. Therefore in case of loading of child's scripts is used, you have to add their host-sources into `script-src` directive.

Comment: I don't understand the removing, you said that script-src-elem 'self'; is removed at all but I see it in the CSP you provided, so should I remove it or not?

Comment: Also if I understand it correctly, I don't need to use "unsafe-inline" if I add nonce to every style, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But if some `<style>` are inserted by LottiePlayer on it's own, you have not possibility to add nonce= attribute to those. Also in case if LottiePlayer uses `element.setAttribute('style', ...)` construction or directly inserts <tag style='...'` (both are considered as inline styles) - you can't fix this with nonce.

Comment: They are sadly, so as of `script-src-elem 'self'`, remove, right?
Is there any way to still implement it without `unsafe-inline`?

Comment: Removing `script-src-elem 'self'` does not mean `'unsafe-inline'` allowed, it means Chrome will fallback to `script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-${nonce}';` and will use it. Alternatively you can chemge it to `script-src-elem 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-${nonce}';` instead of removing (keep it the same as `script-src`).

Comment: Thanks a lot and about `unsafe-inline` in style-src? Is it possible to do this without or not?

Comment: Unfortunately in current version of Lottie player it's [not possible](https://csplite.com/csp/test380/#inline_css) to get rid of `'unsafe-inline'` in the `style-src` directive.